# How can I duplicate a pdf page without doubling the file size?

Tags: pdf

I have a large single page PDF file of a poster that is 200 megs. How can I duplicate the page nine times (so it's a 10 page PDF) without increasing the file size to 2,000 megs?

Basically what I want to do is duplicate the page and only reference the original assets without actually duplicating the image files.

I specifically need multiple copies of pages in the same document. I am aware how to compress the image...this is not the solution that I am looking for. I am also aware that I can simply print a single page 10 times...again, this is not the solution that I am looking for.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have illustrator, Indesign or Acrobat Pro at hand?

Comment: Yes, I have all of those apps.

Comment: Thanks. I see that I can duplicate the pages in Illustrator or InDesign and save it as a pdf without increasing the size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by turning the page into a Template, and then spawn it with the XObject parameter.

You will need Acrobat Pro for that, and you will use Acrobat JavaScript, which means you should have a good look at the Acrobat JavaScript documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I found that I could simply place the poster on a master page in InDesign and duplicate it ten times (or as many times as I needed) without increasing the page size.